# FCM notifications sending POST request in Android

Tags: android, firebase, post, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to receive notifications from `FCM` automatically whenever data in the `Firebase` Database is changed. What I am hoping to do is to send a `POST` request to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send in the `OnDataChange()` method of Firebase Database. I also want the new value of the changed variable to be present in the notification. I have tested the POST request in Advanced `Rest` Client and it is working nicely. What I am looking for is to automate the process so that I do not need to create a server. I am new to Android so I am having a little trouble trying to implement this. **It would be very helpful if someone could show me how to go about creating the `POST` request directly in Android in the format below with the flexibility of being able to change the value of the notification text and body.**

Headers

```
Authorization: key=AAAA4wkL01w:APA91bHu... //Server Key
Content-type: application/json
```

Body

```
{
"to": "eGS6QMzVlbA:APA91bFtY...", //Token
"notification": {
"title": "title",
"body": "body text",
"icon": "ic_notification"
}
}
```

Comment: The problem with the post request from an android device is the authorization part. You would have to distribute the secret key that should be used on the server only. Besides, I think FCM expects the request restricte to a specific domain.

Comment: So what would you suggest I do?

Comment: The android device should hit a server, and have the server send the request to fcm.

Comment: I tried to create a local wamp server and running the following php script: https://pastebin.com/chSEe9vm, but it is not working. The notification does not appear.

Comment: You need to check where it is failing. If you ar using curl, check the curl info after executing the request, and if you get a response check to see the errors.